# How can I set the size of a Win32 dialog in pixels?

Tags: windows, winapi, dialog, rc

I am trying to get a Win32 dialog that is 500x520 px, but in my .rc file, these settings get me a bigger window than I expected.

```
IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 500, 520
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX
```

Is there a scaling factor somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The units in a dialog resource are [dialog units](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644994%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#measurements) which are normalized by the dimensions of the dialog font by a rather convoluted process. You can convert from dialog units to screen pixels with [`MapDialogRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are lots more details in the documentation for [`GetDialogBaseUnits()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the recommended approach is to call `MapDialogRect()` and let it do the hard work for you.

Comment: Yeah, the *reason* you shouldn't use `GetDialogBaseUnits` is because its calculations are based on the default system font, which [no one uses anymore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2008/08/14/8867856.aspx). Unfortunately, if the window in question is not a dialog, you don't have much choice, as `MapDialogRect` doesn't work.

Comment: @CodyGray The documentation for GetDialogBaseUnits explains how the units work. It also tells you which function to call to get the measurements for a non-system font, which you also can use for a non-dialog window.